# Best way to set a language in CodeIgniter with URIs

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, codeigniter-url

I'm using CodeIgniter with po/mo files (I don't like the built-in functions). I have an already-made function that uses get variables to set the cookie with the language.

Now, CodeIgniter doesn't have the get, but uses URIs. This is the function that I'm using (it fires in the constructor):

```
private function locale(){

    $cookie_name = $this->cookie_lang;
    $uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3);

    if ($this->tools->isArray($uri)){
        $locale = $uri['locale'];
    }

    if ($locale) {
        setcookie("$cookie_name", $locale, 0, "/");
    } else {
        if( !isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) && empty($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) ) {
            setcookie("$cookie_name", 'it', 0, "/");
            $locale = 'it';
        } else {
            $locale = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
        }
    }   
    putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
    bindtextdomain("default", "./locale");
    textdomain("default");
    $this->locale = $locale;
    return true;
}
```

It works perfectly. Setting the language is just a matter of appending:

```
locale/x
```

to the URL. The problem is that I use URIs for other purposes (for example loading a page)

```
page/x
```

This results in very long URLs, like:

```
www.site.com/controller/method/page/x/locale/y
```

just to be able to set the language.

What would be an easier (or better) method to set a language?

Comment: I think this is quite an elegant method and very SEO friendly at least as long as the order of your parameters doesn't change. Otherwise duplicate URLs might appear for the same content, which, at least as much as I know, is bad for SEO.

Comment: Thanks, The order shouldn't change on that regard I am safe.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Session](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) to manage your language system.
You can put default session in `MY_Controller` and get from config file (`$config['language']`).

Don't confuse yourself and client with URI. URI will have a duplication.
If you need to prioritize SEO, don't do that.